# How to verify web text while excluding random vars with ruby/watir

Tags: ruby, regex, watir

I have this text and need to verify the bolded words only in each line:

**Insured Direct Bill / 16.67%:** $xxx.xx **down, includes the Policy Fee and Financial Responsibility Fee, and 5 installments of** $xxx.xx (**does not include** $x.xx **installment fee)**

Insured Direct Bill / 25%: $xxx.xx down, includes the Policy Fee and Financial Responsibility Fee, and 5 installments of $xxx.xx (does not include $x.xx installment fee)

Electronic Funds Transfer: $xxx.xx down, includes the Policy Fee and Financial Responsibility Fee, and 5 installments of $xxx.xx (does not include $x.xx installment fee)

I'm assuming I'll need to use:

foo = REGEX

@browser.text.include?(foo)

I'm stuck at how to get it to see everything other than the currency amounts.  [^$\d+.\d+] excludes all the currency but includs the 5 and 16.67

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regex = /Insured Direct Bill \/ 25%: \$(\d+\.\d+) down, includes the Policy Fee and Financial Responsibility Fee, and 5 installments of \$(\d+\.\d+) \(does not include \$(\d+\.\d+) installment fee\)/

@browser.text.match(regex)
```

Comment: Ended up using: 

if 

/Insured Direct Bill \/ 25%: \$(\d+\.\d+) down, includes the Policy Fee, and 5 installments of \$(\d+\.\d+) \(does not include \$(\d+\.\d+) installment fee\)/.match(@browser.text) 

then puts"Language Verified" 

else puts"Language Verify Failed" 

end

Answer (score 1):

There are some regex lessons in [Marick's book **Everyday Scripting with Ruby**.](http://pragprog.com/titles/bmsft/everyday-scripting-with-ruby) I recommend them to strengthen your capability if you need to use regex from time to time.